# Indentation in list of figures and tables

Tags: table-of-contents

I am working on a memoir document class in overleaf. The issue I keep running into is in the list of table and figures. I need to add prefix "Figure" and "Table" to the number in the LOF and LOT. I'm using following lines to do this:

{%

```
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoffigures%
```

}

The problem I'm facing is that some of my figures have long captions, and after adding the prefix, the second line of caption doesn't appear to be aligned in the LOF as shown in the figure:
[image]

I tried adding the following command to adjust the issue:

{%

```
\usepackage{tocloft}%
\cftsetindents{table}{0em}{4em}%
\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{Table }%
```

}

But I get the following error message:

```Command \cfttabpresnum undefined````

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!! If the answer meets your requirement, please accept by checking the green tickmark on left side of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `\renewcommand*{\cftfigurename}{Figure\space}` to add the word Figure.

To add the word Table in the LoT use    `\renewcommand*{\cfttablename}{Table\space}`

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\renewcommand*{\cftfigurename}{Figure\space} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\renewcommand*{\cfttablename}{Table\space} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
\begin{document}
    
    \listoffigures  
    
    \listoftables
            
    \chapter{ONE}
    
    \begin{figure}[hb!]
        \caption{As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of
            practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things
            in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be
            used as a canon for our understanding.}
    \end{figure}


    \begin{table}[hb!]
        \caption{As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of
        practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things
        in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be
        used as a canon for our understanding.}
    
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly.